# Notification Resume Activity

Tags: android, notifications, resume

I know, there are several questions of this type but I tried all of it and it still doesn't work.
Ok, for my app; I've got an Activity. In this Activity, there are 4 Tabs, and the fourth one contents a list and a record button. When I am pushing record, there is a GPS Listener which starts. After getting a new gps value, it pushes it into the list.
This works so far!
If I click the Home Button it still works, if I longpress it then. It resumes that Activity with the specific Tab open and the list still hold the listitems and the gps listener is still active.
This works also fine!
Now I wanted to add a notification, which shows the count of gps values of the list as .number. On every new gps signal, it updates the notification icon with the new number. This is no problem, but the action to click on the notification totally screws up my application.

The actual code looks like this:

```
public void callNotify(String text) {
    notif = new Notification();
    Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this, tabactivity.class);
    contentIntent.putExtra("fid", this.specialvalue);
    contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notif.icon = R.drawable.icon;
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.app_name), text,
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, contentIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    notif.ledARGB = Color.RED;
    notif.ledOnMS = 200;
    notif.ledOffMS = 200;
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS
        | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
        | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
    notif.number = notifyNumber;
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyNumber, notif);
}

public void updateNotify(String text) {
    notifyNumber++;
    notif.number = (int) (notifyNumber / 2);
    Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this, tabactivity.class);
    contentIntent.putExtra("fid", this.specialvalue);
    contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.app_name), text,
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, contentIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    mNotificationManager.cancel((notifyNumber - 2));
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyNumber, notif);
}
```

So, the updateNotify() is called on a new gps signal. And the callNotify() is the first one, before it starts the gps listener. And, yeah, the notifyNumber/2 was my intention, because I work with that number further.

If I compile it like this, and click on the Notification, it opens a NEW tabactivity on the first tab. If I click back then, I get a lot of errors (database is still open, nullpointers and stuff). I think because it starts a new tabactivity and the other one is still open, 'cause I can see the gps listener is still working.

So, what I want is, that I can do the following:
I open my app, go to the tabactivity, open tab 4, click record. If I click back then, it should hide the app, also, if I just click the home button. But there is a notification.
If I click on that one, it should just show the hidden activity again and thats it. 
So, what I am doing wrong there?
I thought, the Flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP should solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is happening here is a little confusing so bear with me here.

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` according to the docs `If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.` So if the current activity is not at the top of the history stack it will be relaunched.

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` again from the docs `If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.`

By default the `TabActivity` will always open to tab 0, you can use `setDefaultTab` to change that via code. Each Tab in the TabHost is also a new `Intent`

> If I compile it like this, and click
>   on the Notification, it opens a NEW
>   tabactivity on the first tab. If I
>   click back then, I get alot of errors
>   (database is still open, nullpointers
>   and stuff).

This is happening *I think* because the current `Intent` is tab4 (in reality its #3, 0,1,2,3) and your notification is bringing up the `tabactivity.class`. Since it is not active or on top of the stack, every act on top of it is closed, including tab4.

> So, what I want is, that I can do the
>   following: I open my app, go to the
>   tabactivity, open tab 4, click record.
>   If I click back then, it should hide
>   the app, also, if I just click the
>   home button. But there is a
>   notification. If I click on that one,
>   it should just show the hidden
>   acitivity again and thats it. So, what
>   I am doing wrong there? I thought, the
>   Flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP should solve
>   the problem?

You are confusing what the flags do and what happens with the `home` and `back` keys. Hitting `home` will hide your activity and the notification should work fine with those flags (once you fix the problem I mentioned earlier).  When you hit `back` though, Android ends the current `Activity` and takes it off the stack. Since there is nothing under it, you are forced to relaunch from scratch when you press the notification.

Comment: Well, actually I know, why its jumping on the first tab. The Tabactivity starts usually at the first tab, but the fourth tab has got that gps list.
So for me ist logically, that its opening the tabactivity twice. Because the initial data of the list and stuff isn't loaded at that time. So, the Flags are wrong? I dont get it somehow...

Comment: Oh wait...it seems to work, if I just use FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and not both. Ok, if that was the mistake, I totally missunderstood the docs. Sorry!