# Android Phonegap app - Bringing activity to front

Tags: android, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, background-foreground

I am in the process of teaching myself how to work with Phonegap notifications on Android.  Whilst displaying a notification appears to be a fairly straightforward process

```
public void triggerTestNotification(String tag, int id,Context ctxt) 
{
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, PallActivity.class);
  notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

  notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0,  
  notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  Notification not = new Notification.Builder(ctxt)
  .setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Title")
  .setTicker("Tick tock")
  .setAutoCancel(true) 
  .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
  .setSmallIcon(ctxt.getApplicationInfo().icon).build();
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)    
   ctxt.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   notificationManager.notify(tag, id, not);
 }
```

what I have found rather more difficult is the following

- The user launches the app
- The user goes away and starts doing something else - the app is backgrounded
- A notification arrives
- Is displayed
- The user clicks on the notification.

At this point the app should come back to the foreground.  I thought my intent code

```
public class PallActivity extends Activity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  finish();
  forceMainActivityReload();
 }

 private void forceMainActivityReload()
 {
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  Intent launchIntent =    
  pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());           
  startActivity(launchIntent);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() 
 {
  super.onResume();
  final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
  this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notificationManager.cancelAll();
 }

}
```

would deal with this but it does nothing at all.  Clearly, I am getting something wrong here - perhaps in the Intent flags.  I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to put me on the right track

Comment: why do you call `finish` in `onCreate` ?

Comment: I placed the `finish()` there because I saw it in another plugin.  However, I have tried my code with `finish()` moved to the bottom of `onCreate` as well as removed all together.  The app still does not get back to the foreground.

Comment: And can you please say what is the purpose of the Pall activity - I mean it immediately redirects to the launcher activity of your app. Isn't `PallActivity` your launcher activity? Can you include your manifest?

Comment: First of all use [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) and from your notificationIntent remove the following: notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `finish();` from your oncreate, it will call finish before you proceed anywhere.

Instead of starting PallActivity, from which is *seems* you are intending to start a second activity or at least treating the PallActivity as a second activity. You don't need to kick start it like that from within `forceMainActivityReload();`. I would be starting the activity you wish to start from the notification intent, rather than making it more complex and confusing the issue.

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;   
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Ensure that the context you are using is:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

And, as mentioned in the comments remove these from the notification:

```
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Here's a plethora of more detail if required:

[Resume an activity when clicked on a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163367/resume-an-activity-when-clicked-on-a-notification)

[Android: How to resume an App from a Notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047683/android-how-to-resume-an-app-from-a-notification)

[resuming an activity from a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386542/resuming-an-activity-from-a-notification?rq=1)

[Notification Resume Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566010/notification-resume-activity)

[Intent to resume a previously paused activity (Called from a Notification)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247902/intent-to-resume-a-previously-paused-activity-called-from-a-notification)

[Android: resume app from previous position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303663/android-resume-app-from-previous-position)

[How to make notification intent resume rather than making a new intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305088/how-to-make-notification-intent-resume-rather-than-making-a-new-intent)

Comment: Thanks, Yvette - the range of helpful links you have provided is particularly appreciated.